# Add-in not activated in compose mode on Outlook for Mac

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have added a manifest file to show web add-in in the Compose and Read modes of Outlook.

The add-in is working fine except when the user clicks on an email address link (`xxx@yz.com`) in the body of an Outlook email. This is opening the Outlook Compose experience but my add-in is shown as disabled in the ribbon

This is happening on Outlook 2016 for Mac, version 15.39

[image]

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Thanks for raising it. It's bug in Mac outlook. We are working on it. Will update the thread once fix is out.